Storage account not found. The selected service connection support storage account of arm type only
I’m trying to copy files to Azure files share using azure file copy task but facing below error
Storage account not found. The selected service connection support storage account of arm type only
Any insights ?
Looks like many are facing this issue but couldn’t find fix

The question is lacking detail. I assume this is a task in a DevOps pipeline? Where are you copying from and to?

Yes, this is a task in ado pipeline where we are using workload federation identity as service connection. We copying to azure blob storage (azure file share)

Self-hosted or Microsoft hosted build agents? What identity does the agent run under? What path are you specifying in source and destination? Can you update question please.

Self hosted, we are using vmss pool agent . I’m creating a local file and adding it as source and destination is azure container

Is your destination like this: https://xxxxxx.file.core.windows.net/share/dest_file? Because the task doesn't support UNC paths.

We had a successfully deploying pipeline using Azure Connection Type Azure Classic which we started getting this error on ("The storage account 'xxxxx' was not found"). It was resolved by changing the Connection Type to Azure Resource Manager.

